# ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars while converting list to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

I have a dataset of images and I am using PIL and torch tensor to convert them in tensors in a loop and storing them in  a list.

```
def preprocess(string):
    return torch.FloatTensor(np.ascontiguousarray(np.array((PIL.Image.open(string)).convert('RGB'))[:, :, ::-1].transpose(2, 0, 1).astype(np.float32) * (1.0 / 255.0)))

import os
folder_name = 'folder name and path'
train1 = []
for item in folder_name:
    x = preprocess(item)
    train1.append(x)
```

Now before train I want to convert the list to np.array using:

```
train1 = np.array(train1)
```

This shows the error:

```
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

I also printed the shapes and types of the constituents of list train1 and found that they are tensors as expected.

Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the error might be due to the way `np.array` handles `list` as arguments. Something under the hood just does not go well with pytorch tensor.

You can instead first stack the tensors and call the `.numpy()` method on it.

```
train1 = torch.stack(train1, dim=0).numpy()
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to convert from FloatTensors to numpy arrays should be:

```py
train1.append(x.numpy())
```

Comment: Wont I lose the tensors like this?

Comment: Wasn't it your point to convert the tensors to numpy arrays? Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Yes. So I now just changed the code like this: def preprocess(string):
    return (np.ascontiguousarray(np.array((PIL.Image.open(string)).convert('RGB'))[:, :, ::-1].transpose(2, 0, 1).astype(np.float32) * (1.0 / 255.0)))